# Open folder in Android/Xamarin.Android programatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to open folder programatically. I used the below code but no luck

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    var uri=Uri.Parse("/storage/emulated/0/myFolder");
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
   // activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "choose folder")); 
    activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

It shows various apps like Phone, Messaging, ES File Explorer, contacts etc.  I want to open the default file explorer to open that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Amit if want to open the default file explorer, you can do that in Native Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");//set type , here is setted to every type.
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Other types :

```
intent.setType("image/*"); //set type be image
intent.setType("audio/*"); //set type be audio
intent.setType("video/*"); //set type be video （mp4 3gp be suported in android）
intent.setType("video/*;image/*");//set type be all video and image
```

And when back to app ,can deal with file in here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //no choose no continue to here
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //get file's url , so last can get file
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        actualimagecursor.moveToFirst();
        String img_path = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
        File file = new File(img_path);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also in this way can open the specified file, need to use method `setDataAndType` like follow:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(dir.getParentFile()), "file/*.txt");
```

the `dir` is the `File` folder where file in this,like follow:

```
String compName = AppString.getCompanyName();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + compName + "/OSC_DATA/";
File dir = new File(path);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

> If just want to scan file use other file explorer application , also can use intent to open other Application.However you should now the package name of it:

```
public void doStartApplicationWithPackageName(String packagename) {

    PackageInfo packageinfo = null;
    try {
        packageinfo = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (packageinfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent resolveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    resolveIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    resolveIntent.setPackage(packageinfo.packageName);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfoList = mContext.getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(resolveIntent, 0);

    ResolveInfo resolveinfo = resolveinfoList.iterator().next();
    if (resolveinfo != null) {
        String packageName = resolveinfo.activityInfo.packageName;

        String className = resolveinfo.activityInfo.name;
        // LAUNCHER Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);

        intent.setComponent(cn);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

using like this:

```
doStartApplicationWithPackageName("com.android.documentsui")
```

This package name might be different in different android system.When you use this way need to be sure the correct package name in current system.

Comment: The main problem of `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` is: It opens the file browser window and when user click on any items, its closes and returns to the main activity of the app. I don't want user to pick the content (as Get_Content do). I just want to open the folder just like we open the link in the browser and user is free to do with that.

Comment: Hi , if just scan file in local . You can use intent to open file explorer application by its package name.I will update answer.

Comment: Isn't any way to launch default file manager because we aren't aware of package name to launch that and different device have different file manager.

Comment: Other way also need package name.So maybe need create own file manager , can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootPath = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:";
 var yourPath = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{rootPath}%2f[your-folder-path]"); // %2f refers to '/'

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

            intent.SetDataAndType(yourPath, "*/*");     
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            intent.SetPackage("com.google.android.documentsui");          

            try
            {
                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions here (e.g., folderPath does not exist)
            }
```

Use this code to open your specified directory using documentsui